# what violates the first normalization rule

Tags: database-design, normalization

I was convinced that what violated the first normation rule was having a multivalued column.

```
 id  name    friends
 1   'john'  'Maycon, Gabriel'
```

That has multiple names in the same column.

Compound columns don't violate the rule because they are atomic.

```
 id  name    localization
 1   'john'  'SP, Brazil'
```

That is not multivalued, it is just compound.

But now I read that just having a table with a primary key is enough to have the first normalization rule met.

What is correct?

Comment: There is no agreed notion of 1NF. [Normalization in database management system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623169/normalization-in-database-management-system) (Roughly speaking, all involve replacing some table with parameterized structure by some table(s) with a column per parameter.) **Quote the textbook/reference you were told to use.** Ask 1 specific question about the 1st place you are stuck evaluating/applying it.

Comment: Research is expected for a good question. [First Normal Form: Definitive Definition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/161119/43932) [Is there an agreed upon definition of 1NF and 2NF?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/299205/43932) etc [ask] [Help]